# How to style the settings pane in windows metro app with Blend?

Tags: css, windows-8, expression-blend

I would like to build the style for some windows 8 Metro Application.

How can I display the settings pane in Blend?

For instance, the `settings.html` declared in the `default.js` as described below:

```
app.onsettings = function (eventObject) {
    eventObject.detail.applicationcommands = { "prefs": { title: "Preferences", href: "/pages/prefs/prefs.html" } };
    WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.populateSettings(eventObject);
};
```

Another related question is :
How can I display the search results page in Blend?

Comment: Um, the setting charm is not part of your application. Your application is responsible for the settings pane, but not the charm itself.

Comment: Apparently, I did not explain myself very well. I mean, of course, the settings pane, in other words the html pages I need to write.

Comment: Now I just edited the question, if it is clearer, could you please remove the down vote?

Comment: I did not downvote the question

Comment: O_o second downvote here ! What a mess ! For information "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)"... Please tell me why this question does not show any research effort or why it is unclear or not useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to programmatically call "the settings pane" by such a code:

```
function scenario5ShowSettingsFlyout() {
    WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.showSettings("prefs", "../../pages/prefs/prefs.html");
}
```

More information are available in the scenario 5 of [the microsoft official sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49).

Answer (score -2):

Try the interactive mode in Blend which allows you to launch your application directly inside Blend otherwise just associate a CSS file (pref.css for example) to your HTML page (pref.html) then style your elements.

Hope this help.

Comment: The interactive mode do not let us to display search charm or settings charm in order to launch a new search and have the search result page displayed or in order to launch one of the settings pane...

Comment: It would be better to check something before suggesting the poster try it.